# How to conditional format based on cell color

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have excel 2016 I am trying to conditionally format adjacent cells based on the color of the cell i.e. if B5 is green then A5 should become green. Is this possible? I'm not concerned at this time about the contents of the cell just the color.

Comment: No it is not possible via Conditional Formatting

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished with a user-defined function. First, create the function to identify the fill color of the cell:

```
Function IdentifyColor(CellToTest As range)

'Returns R + (256 * G) + (65536 * B)
'IdentifyColor = 255 for red, 65280 for green, etc.
IdentifyColor = CellToTest.Interior.Color

End Function
```

Then create a conditional format formula for cell A5 based on this formula: `=IdentifyColor(B5)=65280`

It may be easier to use `HEX2DEC` to specify colors. Therefore, the formula would become:
`=IdentifyColor(B5)=HEX2DEC("00FF00")`

`[image: Screenshot of Conditional Formatting Rule]

If the color of cell B5 is green (RGB value 0, 255, 0), the formula returns true and the format of cell A5 will change to how you specify.

You may need to press <kbd>F9</kbd> after changing the formatting to force recalculation and make sure the conditional formatting is applied.